# Trying to connect raspberry Pi 3 to a laptop with ethernet, but IP address not showing up

Tags: ethernet

total Raspberry Pi newbie here. I only just opened the box.

Because I don't have a monitor / keyboard i'm trying to use a very old Windows laptop. It's at crawling speed.

I've tried to complete it using this tutorial -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AJ7skYS5bjI

But whenever I go into "local area connection status" for the Rasberry PI connected by ethernet and click the internet protocol version 4, there is no IP address provided. I manually typed in the IP which should be there - 192.168.137.1 but that eventually leads to a network error on MabaxTerm. Yes, I have allowed internet connection sharing.

I'm about to give up on Pi.... Please help

Comment: I have a keyboard/mouse/monitor that I use to bring up a new Raspberry Pi. I have heard that it is possible to set it up so that the RasPi can communicate over a dedicated ethernet cable, but I haven't figured out how to do that without having set up the RasPi manually. Sorry.

Comment: Probably the easiest solution would be a usb-to-serial cable (3.3v). You can get them, in the US, from Sparkfun.com or Pishop.us.

Comment: Unless you say what YOU DID no one can help. No one is going to look at YouTube to guess what you did.

Comment: The issue seems to be that you've misconfigured ICS (internet connection sharing) on the windoze computer - nothing to do with the raspberry pi, as it will, out of the box, use DHCP (if it can find one) to get an IP address